# C++ open a file as read-only

Tags: c++, file-io

I have written a program which opens a file then displays line by line its contents (text file)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string STRING;        
    ifstream infile;    
    infile.open(argv[1]);   
    if (argc != 2)  
    {
        cout << "ERROR.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    if(infile.fail())
    {
        cout << "ERROR.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while(!infile.eof())
        {
            getline(infile,STRING); 
            cout<<STRING + "\n"; 
        }   
        infile.close(); 
        return 0; 
    }
}
```

What do I need to add to make the file be read only ?

(`infile.open(argv[1])` is where am guessing something goes)

Comment: OT: Don't do `while(!infile.eof())`, do `while(getline(infile,STRING))`

Comment: @Bart please elaborate

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The class `ifstream` is for reading only so, problem solved. Also, did you really mean to check `argc` *after* using `argv[1]` ?

On the other hand, when you use `fstream` you need to specify how you want to open the file:

```
fstream f;
f.open("file", fstream::in | fstream::out); /* Read-write. */
```

Answer (score 2):

The default *mode* parameter of `open` for `ifstream` class is `ios::in`. That is

```
infile.open(argv[1]);
```

is same as:

```
infile.open(argv[1], ios::in);
```

So you are opening the file in read-only mode.

Answer (score 1):

You already open the file for read-only. Your can't write to it if you use `ifstream`. Even:

```
infile.rdbuf()->sputc('a');
```

is guaranteed to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything as the default value for the openmode is already `ios_base::in`. So you're already good to go :)
See here for more details: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open